# Strange Behavior In CharacterSet.contains() Method, With High UTF8 Characters Mixed With ASCII

Tags: arrays, swift, string, set, nscharacterset

Here's the deal: I am creating a StringProtocol extension to add the ability to do a split, based on a character set (any character in the set is used to split -greedy comparison).

The issue is that I am having difficulties comparing against a CharacterSet that has BOTH low-number ASCII characters AND high-number UTF8 characters.

If I present only UTF8 high or ASCII, the match works fine.

I created a playground that illustrates this.

The strange result is the second-to-last printout ("`Test String 2 does not have a space or a joker.`"). That should say "does."

The issue is that the space in the CharacterSet matches, but the joker card does not.

Any ideas? Here's the playground:

```
import Foundation

public extension StringProtocol {
    func containsOneOfThese(_ inCharacterset: CharacterSet) -> Bool {
        self.contains { (char) in
            char.unicodeScalars.contains { (scalar) in inCharacterset.contains(scalar) }
        }
    }
}

let space = " "
let joker = ""
let both = space + joker

let spadesNumberCards = ""
let spadesFaceCards = ""

let testString1 = spadesNumberCards + space + spadesFaceCards
let testString2 = spadesNumberCards + joker + spadesFaceCards
let testString3 = spadesNumberCards + both + spadesFaceCards

print("These Are The Strings We Are Testing:\n")
print("Test String 1: \"\(testString1)\"")
print("Test String 2: \"\(testString2)\"")
print("Test String 3: \"\(testString3)\"")
      
print("\nFirst, See If Any Of the Strings Contain Spaces:\n")
print("Test String 1 does \(testString1.containsOneOfThese(CharacterSet(charactersIn: space)) ? "" : "not ")have a space.")
print("Test String 2 does \(testString2.containsOneOfThese(CharacterSet(charactersIn: space)) ? "" : "not ")have a space.")
print("Test String 3 does \(testString3.containsOneOfThese(CharacterSet(charactersIn: space)) ? "" : "not ")have a space.")

print("\nNext, See If Any Of the Strings Contain Jokers:\n")
print("Test String 1 does \(testString1.containsOneOfThese(CharacterSet(charactersIn: joker)) ? "" : "not ")have a joker.")
print("Test String 2 does \(testString2.containsOneOfThese(CharacterSet(charactersIn: joker)) ? "" : "not ")have a joker.")
print("Test String 3 does \(testString3.containsOneOfThese(CharacterSet(charactersIn: joker)) ? "" : "not ")have a joker.")

print("\nOK, Now it gets weird:\n")

print("Test String 1 does \(testString1.containsOneOfThese(CharacterSet(charactersIn: both)) ? "" : "not ")have a space or a joker.")
print("Test String 2 does \(testString2.containsOneOfThese(CharacterSet(charactersIn: both)) ? "" : "not ")have a space or a joker.")
print("Test String 3 does \(testString3.containsOneOfThese(CharacterSet(charactersIn: both)) ? "" : "not ")have a space or a joker.")
```

Which prints out:

```
These Are The Strings We Are Testing:

Test String 1: " "
Test String 2: ""
Test String 3: " "

First, See If Any Of the Strings Contain Spaces:

Test String 1 does have a space.
Test String 2 does not have a space.
Test String 3 does have a space.

Next, See If Any Of the Strings Contain Jokers:

Test String 1 does not have a joker.
Test String 2 does have a joker.
Test String 3 does have a joker.

OK, Now it gets weird:

Test String 1 does have a space or a joker.
Test String 2 does not have a space or a joker.
Test String 3 does have a space or a joker.
```

Comment: I have observed before that `CharacterSet` does not work well with characters outside of the BMP (basic multilingual plane), perhaps due its heritage from `NSCharacterSet`. You might be better off using a `Set<Character>` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Let me give that a try. The whole deal is to make it easy to use, but turning a simple String into a Set should be ok.

Comment: Actually it seems that `CharacterSet(charactersIn: both)` is broken. With `CharacterSet(both.unicodeScalars)` you get the expected result.

Comment: Oohhh...so the converter is broken. I may still look at using a Set, or even a simple brute-force comparison (This is not meant for industrial use). But your suggestion is cool.

Comment: Yup. You right. If you phrase that as an answer, I'll greencheck you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `CharacterSet.init(charactersIn string: String)` does not work correctly if the string contains characters from both inside and outside the BMP (basic multilingual plane):

```
let s = " "
let cs = CharacterSet(charactersIn: s)
s.unicodeScalars.forEach {
    print(cs.contains($0))
}

// Expected output: true, true
// Actual output:   true, false
```

A workaround is to use create the character set from the sequence of Unicode scalars instead:

```
let cs = CharacterSet(s.unicodeScalars)
```

This will produce the expected output.

But note that this cannot handle the full range of Swift `Character`s (which include grapheme clusters consisting of multiple Unicode scalars). Therefore you might want to work with a `Set<Character>` instead.

Comment: Woo-Hoo! Thanks for the fast turnaround!

Comment: @MartinR Should `CharacterSet` have been called `UnicodeScalarSet`? From what I can tell, the "Character" in "CharacterSet" doesn't mean "Character" as in `Swift.Character`.

Comment: Good point. @MartinR 's point about the grapheme clusters is worth thinking about, as well. I may not do that for this utility (yet), but it's an issue.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: It is named CharacterSet because it is the overlay value type (in the sense of [SE-0069](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md)) of NSCharacterSet. Renaming it has been [discussed and rejected](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-renaming-characterset-to-unicodescalarset/4135).

Comment: @MartinR Oh interesting, I called it! :p It's a shame, because it really has some "surprises" and broken expectations. Rationale: "We made a decision to leave the names of the types the same between Swift and Foundation. It’s a tradeoff for sure, but it seems better than other alternatives. Consistent documentation and hindering a common understanding of purpose for the type would be the biggest challenge if we change the names."